# k-enclosing rectangle in two-colored point set

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I was asked to write an algorithm for the following problem, and discuss complexity:

> - There are p points of two colours, black and white, in an n*m grid.
> - Any cell in the grid can contain 0 or more points, of any colour.
> - We are looking for an axis aligned rectangle, having (0,0) as a corner, containing k black points, and maximizing the number of white points in it.

It was mentioned that this problem is famous and I can use any online resource.

So far, the closest I have found is [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9e04/866ce5d30da84a893c055aa15f09cf8457ff.pdf), which deals with finding exact colored k-enclosing rectangles, that don't necessarily have the origin as a vertex.

Maybe someone here will be able to point me to some resources that discuss this version of the problem?

Comment: hint: just imagine you want to build two n*m arrays $B$ and $W$. $B[i,j]$ and $W[i,j]$ are respectively the total number of black and white points  in the rectangle (left=0, up=0, right=i, down=j). How would you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I had in mind! My initial thought was to first sort the points by x and y coordinates, then write a function that accumulates the number of B and W found for any smaller or equal x and y. I believe the initialization would be in O(p log p + m*n). I would also update a list of size b (number of black points) which stores the best coordinates for a given k - so that the cost of finding the best coordinates for a given k would be in O(1). That said, there may be more optimal solutions out there!

Comment: Also, in terms of literature search, try range trees(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) and range queries/orthogonal range searching.

Comment: Also, a good runtime should not be dependent on $m,n$. Let $(x,y)$ be the farthest point to bottom right, any $O(mn)$-time solution can be turned into an $O(xy)$-time one.

Comment: If you sweep from left to right, notice how the height of all rectangles containing exactly $k$ white points is monotonically decreasing. You can use this to do further pruning.

Comment: Thanks @BearAqua, but your previous suggestion makes me think a tree approach (k-d tree? Range tree?) is possible and would make the initialization phase independent from m or n. I will explore that for now

Comment: @sousben Just using a data structure would not likely result in a speed up. Because you still need to insert all $p$ points into the tree, and that can be a lot of work. What seems interesting is that if you fix a starting configuration of $k$ black points in the upper-left corner, and sweep from left to right, each new rectangle with $k$ black points is found by trading $b$ black points on the lowest rows of the previous rectangle with $b$ black points on the current column.

Comment: @sousben This leads me to believe that with more observations, something like $O(\min\{n,m\}k)$-time is likely possible. This is better than the dynamic programming solution when $k$ is small. To see if we can achieve this bound, some careful implementation details (more specifically, can we query the prefix sum for the "previous" rectangle in $O(1)$-time, when determining the height of a new rectangle wider than the previous one when sweeping) need to be solidified.

Comment: No matter what, it seems like an optimal solution would at least exploit the monotonicity in some way.

Comment: @BearAqua I agree with this statement, in any approach we could do some pruning. I didn't make it clear, but the preprocessing shouldn't be k-specific. It was mentioned that the algorithm should deal with different request after initialization

Answer (score 1):

Ok as you have a working solution but seem concerned by optimization, I will detail here how to do it very efficiently. I assume that your rectangle has to follow the discretized grid (I now have a doubt on it reading your question).

Let's build 2 $n \times m$ count arrays $NB$ and $NW$ which are the number of respectively black and white points in each cell. You can fill these arrays in $O(p)$ as you just have to consider any point and decide which value of the array you increment.

Then you build the 2 $n \times m$ accumulator arrays $RB$ and $RW$. $RB[i, j]$ and $RW[i, j]$ are the number of respectively black and white points in the rectangle (left=0, up=0, right=$j$, down=$i$). You can fill these arrays with a very simple DP using $NW$ and $NR$, in $O(nm)$. Note that computing row after row, and in the row looping on elements, you can break the latter loop whenever $RB > k$.

The overall time complexity will be $O(max(p, nm))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure I agree with the last step. Why not create an array that stores the best_ij for each possible value of k at the same time as we build the accumulator arrays? That would allow to find the best_ij in O(1). Also, we are not looking for all possible best_ij but only one, but that doesn't make a big diff

Comment: Yes you are totally right, I will remove this. In fact you can even can break the computation of any row of $RB$ when it grows over $k$.